# Передача текста + картинок с помощью ajax FormData

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

здравствуйте, как передать ajax Form Data запросом, изображение + другие текстовые значения?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21044798/how-to-use-formdata-for-ajax-file-upload

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что автору было лень набрать три слова в гугле.

Comment: var form = document.querySelector('.my-form'); var data = new formData(form); и далее при формировании AJAX xhr.send(data);

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно отправить изображения AJAX, то

```
var values; // нужные значения сюда (можно с сепаратором $ или &, например)
            // для отправки изображения юзай .toDataURL();
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://example.com/?values"+=values,
   succes: function(data) {
    // делаем все что хотим если успешно
   }
});
```